# SQL to identify customers who placed more than X orders in a given year

Tags: sql

Here's the table I am working with:

```
customer_id  order_id    order_date
101              1       2016-12-11
102              2       2016-12-13
101              3       2017-12-14
103              4       2017-12-15
...             ...           ...
```

I need a SQL to find out how many customers made more than X purchases in 2016 and 2017.

I've gotten the proper answer for it being customer 101, with this code:

```
select
    customer_id
from 
(
    select  
        year(order_date) as order_date_year,
        customer_id,
        count(*) as number_of_orders
    from
        cust_orders
    group by
        year(order_date),
        customer_id
    having
        count(*) >= 3
) as t
group by
    order_date_year,
    customer_id
```

But this doesn't solve for specific years being more than X.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Add fields of subquery to starting select (t.number_of_orders, t order_date_year)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
select c.customer_id
from (
  select customer_id
  from cust_orders 
  where year(order_date) in (2016, 2017)
  group by customer_id, year(order_date)
  having count(*) >= 10
) c
group by c.customer_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Replace `10` with the number of purchases.
Change `2` to the number of years that you want to search for.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tSb8b5rxu2xniPrSFTR4bU/0).

Comment: This is probably a really dumb question, but the lower case c's in there, what are those for? (My SQL knowledge is very basic, trying to learn!). :)

Comment: `c` is the alias of the query inside the parentheses after from.

Comment: Thanks so much! Very informative, and your SQL worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation with a `having` clause to get the counts by year and customer.  Then aggregate again and count the years:

```
select customer_id
from (select customer_id, year(order_date) as year
      from cust_orders co
      group by customer_id, year(order_date)
      having count(*) >= X
     ) x
where year in (2016, 2017)
group by customer_id
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Just for my own knowledge, what is the lower case x for?

Comment: It's an alias for the subquery. Many database platforms require that subqueries in the `FROM` clause be aliased. None (that I'm aware of) throw an error if the alias is there, but several will throw an error if it's missing.